# What does fibre-wise mean?

Tags: differential-geometry, quantum-mechanics

I am doing some exercises in Lagrangian systems in the book *Quantum Mechanics for Mathematicians*. One exercise says:

> Let $f$ be a $C^\infty$ function on a manifold $M$. Show that the Lagrangian systems $(M,L)$ and $(M,L+df)$ (where $df$ is fibre-wise linear function on $TM$) have the same equations of motion.

I do know what $df$ means as a differential form, and I solved the exercise. I just had never read such terminology ("fibre-wise") and I wonder what does that mean.

Comment: "Fibre-wise linear function" means a function which is linear on each fiber of the tangent bundle (that is, on each tangent space).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$TM\xrightarrow\pi M$ is a vector bundle. In particular, this means that for every $p\in M$, the **fibre** $\pi^{-1}\{p\}=T_pM\subseteq TM$ is a vector space.

Saying that $df$ is fiberwise linear means that for every $p\in M$ the function $(df)_p:T_pM\to\mathbb R$ is linear.